# Django silk middleware error

Tags: python, django

Im trying to add django silk to my project, and want to add the user ID for each of the logged requests on my app.

This is how I have my middleware set:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (

    'logger.middleware.LoggerMiddleware',
    'silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',



    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',


    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'middleware.loginrequired.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

As you can see, theres only one middleware above silk. This middleware just adds the user ID to an http header:

```
class LoggerMiddleware:
    """.
    """

    def process_request(self, request):
        session_key = request.COOKIES.get('sessionid')
        print session_key
        if session_key:
            try:
                session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
                uid = session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
                print uid
                request.META['HTTP_USER_ID'] = str(uid)
            except Exception as inst:
                print "the exception: "
                print inst
```

The problem is that every time I try to do a post request I get the exception:

```
Silk middleware has not been installed correctly. Ordering must ensure that Silk middleware can execute process_request and process_response. If an earlier middleware returns from either of these methods, Silk will not have the chance to inspect the request/response objects.
```

Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong and if there is an easier way to record the user that is making the requests on silk?

Answer (score -1):

Add silk middleware in last of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES tuple.

Comment: I found https://github.com/django-silk/silk/issues/65 this issue on django silk that is library issue not your configuration related issue